# put sth on the tip of sb's subconsciousness

Tags: expressions

Is the expression in bold understandable to you?

> "How to put the name of the product ***on the tip of*** my prospective customers' ***subconsciousness*** so that it could be easily retrieved at the next time they see it?"

The above is a sentence I wrote. I did a tweak to a set phrase "on the tip of sb's tongue". The reason I used the word "subconsciousness" is that I need a sound marketing strategy that could help leave an impression on customers. But this needs to be done in a very subtle way. What I am looking for is a mind trick that produces a positive memorable effect on customers with a transient hint or stimulus.

I know the sentence might seem a little bit wordy and hard to read, but that's exactly what I intended to do.

Comment: You could say "How to put the name of the product **into the mind** of prospective customers so that it can be easily retrieved?"

Comment: Why did you want the sentence to be wordy and hard to read?